# Could we merge tags "church" and "christianity"?

Tags: discussion, tag-merge

There are the following tags related to Christianity (in alphabetical order):

- [catholic-church](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catholic-church)
- [christianity](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christianity)
- [church](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/church)
- [pope](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pope)
- [reformation](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reformation)

The first one and the last two are obvious (there is also broad [religion](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/religion) tag). I was thinking about the [church](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/church). At the moment it's excerpt says

> Questions related to the Catholic church in history

but this is in fact what the [catholic-church](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catholic-church) is intended for. If we consider as Church all Christian movement since the death of Jesus, the [christianity](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christianity) is enough. I propose that we make an alias in "church" to "catholic-church" or to "christianity".

I looked at questions tagged with [church](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/church) and think that [christianity](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christianity) would be the best one to be redirected to.

Or maybe "church" is intended to be about Christian places of worship, but no question is about this kind of building.

Answer (score 5):

I do not think that "church" and "Christianity" should be merged. The tag makes sense as being about Christian places of worship. Questions tagged with Christianity should be about the religion as a whole, whereas questions about church should be specifically about the structures themselves. Tags can be removed from posts where they don't make sense, but it doesn't make sense to me to distort the meaning of a tag to fit mistagged questions.

Comment: I have proposed edits to the tag wiki to match your assertions here.  The current tag wiki treats "church" as socio-religious institution; I have proposed "church" as the physical place of worship.

Comment: We should probably scour the questions that are tagged [tag:church] and verify that the tag is appropriate.